# requests module - trying to post

Tags: python, html, validation, post, urllib

I'm using the requests module with python 3.3 and am trying to post data. This is the data I'm trying to post. I've already parsed the values from the html:

```
<form action="/checkoutnow/2" autocomplete="off" class="proceed" id="loginForm" method="post" name="login_form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input id="loginForm" name="execution" type="hidden" value="e21s1"> <input name="token" type="hidden" value="EC-2MJ027776Y1687721"> <input id="incontext" name="incontext" type="hidden" value="0"> <input id="eventID" name="_eventId_submit" type="hidden">

  <div class="" id="loginFields">
    <div class="inputField emailField confidential">
      <label for="email">Email</label> <input autocomplete="off" data-validate-email="true" id="email" name="email" type="email" value="">

      <div class="tip tipHint">
        <div class="tipArrow tipArrowFront tipHintArrowFront"></div>

        <div class="tipArrow tipArrowBack tipHintArrowBack"></div>

        <ul class="tipText tipHintText">
          <li>Did you mean <a class="emailLink" href=""></a>?
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="inputField passwordField confidential">
      <label for="password">Password</label> <input autocomplete="off" id="password" maxlength="22" name="password" type="password" value="">

      <div class="toolTip tip guestTooltip">
        <div class="tipArrow tipArrowFront tipErrorArrowFront"></div>

        <div class="tipArrow tipArrowBack tipErrorArrowBack"></div>

        <div class="tipText tipErrorText">
          Trouble logging in? You can try again, or <a class='submit' href='/checkoutnow/2?execution=e21s1&_eventId_guest' id='guestTooltipLink'>check out as a guest</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons varA">
    <input class="btn full continue" name="_eventId_submit" type="submit" value="Log in to PayPal">

    <div class="forgotPassword secondary" id="forgotPasswordSection">
      <a href='/us/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_account-recovery&amp;from=PayPal' id='forgotPassword' target='_blank'>Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>
    <hr class="sep">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary submit" href="/checkoutnow/2?execution=e21s1&_eventId_guest&token=EC-2MJ027776Y1687721" id="checkoutAsAGuestBtn">Pay with Debit or Credit Card</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my code to get past this. I am using a session btw.

```
payload6 = {'loginFields': {'password': paypalpass, 'email': useremail}, 'token': token, 'execution': execution, 'incontext': incontext, '_eventId_submit': ''}
r = session.post(urlnow, data=payload6)
```

I believe my problem is with the 'loginFields' as after I post, the values are still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST data shouldn't have any nested dicts. `password` and `email` should be top-level keys like `token` and `execution` are, and not nested under `loginFields` like they are now. (I assume `loginFields` is in your payload now because of that `<div id="loginFields">`, but wrappers like that shouldn't have any effect on how the POST data is structured.)

Comment: Ah i tried that before I started using the nested dict for the login field and the pass/email didn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out javascript was generating more variables. Thanks for the help though.